# Обновить значения в таблице и вернуть список

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня есть два запроса.
Первый прочитывает сообщения в чате, меняя флаг `is_read` на `true`.

```
UPDATE MESSAGES 
SET IS_READ = TRUE 
WHERE ROOM_ID = '${this.room}' 
  AND USER_ID != '${this.sender}'
```

Второй возвращает сообщения из часта.

```
SELECT M.MESSAGE_ID, M.ROOM_ID, M.MESSAGE_TEXT, M.USER_ID, M.IS_READ 
FROM MESSAGES AS M 
WHERE M.ROOM_ID = '${this.room}'
```

Я пытаюсь объединить их, так как сейчас у меня два запроса в бд, на обновление и на выборку.

Я пытался объединить их так

```
SELECT M.MESSAGE_ID, M.ROOM_ID, M.MESSAGE_TEXT, M.USER_ID, M.IS_READ 
FROM ( UPDATE MESSAGES 
       SET IS_READ = TRUE 
       WHERE ROOM_ID = '1' 
         AND USER_ID != '71') 
WHERE M.ROOM_ID = 1
```

Как можно объединить эти два запроса, чтобы был один?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WITh cte AS ( UPDATE messages 
              SET is_read = TRUE 
              WHERE room_id = 1 
              AND user_id != 71 )
SELECT message_id, room_id, message_text, user_id, is_read 
FROM messages 
WHERE room_id = 1
```

Если возникнут вопли насчёт того, что CTE не возвращает ничего или что оно не используется в основном запросе (проверять лень), то

```sql
WITh cte AS ( UPDATE messages 
              SET is_read = TRUE 
              WHERE room_id = 1 
              AND user_id != 71 
              RETURNING room_id)
SELECT m.message_id, m.room_id, m.message_text, m.user_id, m.is_read 
FROM messages m
JOIN cte ON m.room_id = cte.room_id
```